# Python chatbot: how to return sequence of responses in order instead of random?

Tags: python, chatbot

I followed a tutorial to create a simple chat bot [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ea9jgBjQxEs).
The thing is that in the tutorial the responses for "unknown" are returned randomly with `random.randrange` I wanted to know the opposite of this thing but could not find it on google, do you know how to return these responses in the correct order instead?

[image: screenshot of responses for unknown question]

```
def unknown():
    response = ["Could you please rephrase that?",
                "I didn't get that",
                "I don't understand",
                "What does that mean?"
                "I didn't get that, I'm not as good as Leela yet"
                "Maybe you should go back to work instead"][random.randrange(5)]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and Python coding. Your question is a little unclear. From what I can gather you would need to keep track of the position of the last answer given, and increase the counter to the next one next time, looping back to the start once all answers have been given. Does that sound accurate?

Comment: Hello yes sorry if this is unclear.
the tutorial returns randomly the question between the 5 possibilities with the thing called "random.randrange" 
instead I would like that for any unknown question, these responses are sent in the correct order, and when all sent, loop back to start.

Comment: hello @RobinAndrews is the question more clear now? thanks